# How to work with Dragonfly's before_serve block to watermark pdf files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dragonfly-gem

I'm trying to serve PDF files that are watermarked with a users email address and timestamp at the time of downloading a file using the dragonfly gem and I'm having a bit of trouble working with the before_serve block. What I'm not able to work out is how to use the job object dragonfly passes to the block and how to apply a custom processor. Calling process on the job object directly doesn't appear to run the processor

```rb
app.configure do |config|
  config.server.before_serve do |job, env|
    user = # user record grabbed from database
    job.process(:watermark, user: user)
  end
end
```

However if I call process on the dragonfly object returned by the rails model the pdf is processed correctly but I'm not sure how to actually instruct dragonfly on what to send to the browser

```rb
app.configure do |config|
  config.server.before_serve do |job, env|
    user = # user record grabbed from database
    report = # report grabbed from database
    report.pdf.process(:watermark, user: user)
  end
end
```

So in both cases the same file is returned to the browser, the original non-watermarked version. Maybe I'm trying to get dragonfly to do something it's not supposed to do in a before_serve block? My alternative implementation would be to block access to direct file downloads and do all of this in a rails controller instead. I'd like to use dragonfly's before_serve block if possible as I've already added all of the authentication within the block to make sure users are allowed to download the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation it would appear the best solution is to block all direct file access in the before_serve block and use a standard rails controller to watermark the file and present it for download.